# registry cleanup after uninstalling msi's

Tags: registry

I wonder, what is the best way to clean up registry after uninstalling software?

I have a project that contains multiple msi. In custom action I do clean every entry I writing

but when searching registry after uninstallation, i find out a lot of entries that must have been created by msi's.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tools such as CCleaner to clear the unwanted registry entries and unwanted file extension linkages.Will remove the clutter from your registry or you can even purchase some high end tools to de frag and clean registry.

Answer (score 0):

A good Registry cleaner can help you scan your problem and then clean it up, this one may help you

http://www.comtips.net/go/perfectbooster.php